# Page header problems in Google Chrome when scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I found a problem in Google Chrome on Ubuntu: When I scroll the page with the mouse roller, the page header doesn't look good when I scroll to the top of the page (sometimes the problem is fixed after a few seconds, sometimes not). It happens only in some websites. Is it a known bug of Google Chrome? I'm using Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: You can see it on https://viggo-backend-tests.herokuapp.com/ , but only if you create and activate your account - remember to change the domain name before you activate your account. I checked now and it only happens on some windows - it might be related to memory.

Comment: Sorry, have to run. I'll look over this tonight. Cheers!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bug on my machine. Still, i noticed a .clearfix class on the last <li> item in the menu. You should remove that empty list item and put the class on the <ul> tag ( <ul class="menu clearfix"> ) to give it height. That technique needs the class on the parent of floated elements. EDIT: otherwise i don't see any problem in the header...

Comment: @IulianAnghel OK, I removed the `<li class="clearfix"></li>` and added class `clearfix` to the `<ul class="menu clearfix">`.